# Express middleware stuck in at the middle

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to using express().router as middleware for express server.

this is the code for the express server -

```
const server = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
server.use(logger("short"));

server.use(respomnseTime(4)) // The number indicate how digits we want

server.use('/', mRouter);

server.use((request, response, next)=>{
  mUtil.print("Request IP: " + request.url);
  mUtil.print("Request Date: " + new Date());
  next();
})

server.use((request, response, next)=>{
  mUtil.auth(request, response, next);
})

server.use((request, response, next)=>{
  console.log("Middleware 2");
  next();
})
```

this is the code for the router (another file) -

```
const router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.send({ express: 'YOUR EXPRESS BACKEND IS CONNECTED' });
});

router.get('/user/:username', (request, response)=>{

});

router.get('/about', (request, response)=>{

});

router.get('/contact', (request, response)=>{

});
```

It looks like he middlewares after -

```
server.use('/', mRouter);
```

not running. I thought the problem happens because there is no call to `next()` function, but I'm not sure how to write it. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: on line 5 you misspelled `responseTime`. Does the problem persist if you fix that?

Comment: `not running` - What is this mean?

Comment: It looks like the get function works but the running stop after this point (there is no error, the server sends me an answer) and does not continue to the middlewares function. But if I change the location of the middleware which uses the router to be the last middleware it works fine.

Comment: Are you still getting an error when you fix the typo? If so, what is the error specifically?

Answer (score 0):

you should export your router like below

```
module.exports = router;
```